# Call a Javascript Function and Update my Form Element at the same time

Tags: forms, javascript, ajax

This is my ajax callback function

```
function myid_search_idnumber($form, $form_state)
{
    return $form['id'];
}
```

It updates the values in `$form['id']`. But Because I wanted to call a javascript function as well as update the form, I added a few codes:

```
function myid_search_idnumber($form, $form_state)
{
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'myid_update_id_number'); 
    $page = array( '#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands, ); 
    ajax_deliver($page); 

    return $form['id'];
}
```

The three lines of code added above, calls a javascript function.

```
$.fn.myid_update_id_number = function(){   
    alert('Wew');         
}
```

Performing those only calls the javascript function but does not update anymore my form. How will I call my javascript and at the same time update my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to ad to the above answer by Ollie.
To return `form['id']` too (same as the default behavior), you can use [ajax_command_replace](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_replace/7)

```
function myid_search_idnumber($form, $form_state){
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace(NULL, render($form['id']));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'myid_update_id_number', array($form['id'])); 
    $page = array( 
         '#type' => 'ajax', 
         '#commands' => $commands, 
      ); 
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ajax_deliver()` calls `ajax_footer()`, which basically terminates the request, and exits. Hence your `return $form['id']` isn't called.

Why don't you simply add the form_id as a parmeter to `ajax_command_invoke`? Haven't tested it, but it should work. Have a look at the documentation for the `ajax_command_invoke` function in /includes/ajax.inc around line 1185.

`function myid_search_idnumber($form, $form_state){
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'myid_update_id_number', array($form['id'])); 
    $page = array( 
         '#type' => 'ajax', 
         '#commands' => $commands, 
      ); 
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }`